# Loot amount in town hall

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image]

I want to know about this. How this can happen no loot amount after crushing the opponent town hall. Everyone told that town hall have one part of loot amount... but three times i got nothing from town hall even loot money is more than 2 lakh....ya its true rest of the time i got impressive amount from town hall.

Answer (score 1):

> - **Town Hall**: There is a portion of all three resources that can be
>     stolen inside the Town Hall. As the Town Hall acts as a storage
>     building for all resources, the percentage of available resources is
>     equal to the percentage of available resources from the regular
>     storages; for example, if 20% of Gold can be stolen from the storages,
>     20% of the Gold held by the Town Hall can be stolen. Note, however,
>     that its loot is only obtained upon its destruction; if it is damaged
>     partially, no loot will be yielded.

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids

Sometimes, most of the loot is stored in the collectors, mines and drills. So, you need to figure out how the full collectors, mines and drills look like and a rough idea about how much their capacity is for each level.

So, if the storages look empty for a certain resource, there's a good chance that the town hall doesn't contain much of that type of resource.

*Happy Clashing!*